# action takes the null object in the image passing of the form a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm sorry for my English. Takes a problem with the file transfer (image) to the server. If transferred to a single file from only one form on the page, then everything is fine, but when I try to do several forms (using ajax), data is transmitted at all. Total 7 on the form of images (especially databases) each of which is typified model:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Data { get; set; }
    public byte[] Img { get; set; }
    public string MIMEType { get; set; }
}
```

Img - property to get data from database, Data - set from page

"Common" view:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    <div id="image-@i">
        @Html.Partial("EditImage", new Image() { Id = Model.Imgs[i-1], Number = i, ProductId = Model.Id })
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
}
```

And main problem, view "EditImage":

```
@model Image

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditImage", "Product", null, new AjaxOptions() 
             { 
                 Url = "/Product/EditImage", 
                 HttpMethod = "Post", 
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                 UpdateTargetId = "image-" + Model.Number.ToString() 
             }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MIMEType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Number)

    <div class="mini-image left">
        <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Home", new { Id = Model.Id })" />
    </div>

    <input type="file" name="Data" />

    <input id="ok-@Model.Number" type="submit" value="Send"/>
    <input id="del-@Model.Number" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
}
```

I set breakpoint in first line of action. Properties "ProductId" And "Number" were passed. Data is null :( I tried set id="Data", id="Data@(Model.Number)" unsuccessfully.

UPDATE: it's harder than i think, Request.Files.Count equals 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to use some javascript libraries for uploading files by ajax. JQuery ajax functions can't send files somehow.